# AADSTS50011: the specified reply URL does not match what is configured

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.0

I have seen a number of threads on this topic already. Apologies for adding another one but I haven't been able to solve my issue. I've created an ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC application and published to Azure. The error is:

AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application: 'a7f1d462-fce3-402c-9975-ac6f00c93a50'.

```
My appsettings.json is:
"AzureAd": {
   "ClientId": "a7f1d462-fce3-402c-9975-ac6f00c93a50",
   "Domain": "sentech.us",
   "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
   "TenantId": "<removed>",
   "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
   "ClientSecret": "<removed>",
   "AppIDURL": "https://sentech.us/LoginTest",
   "ConfigView": "MVC"
} 

Reply URLs:
   https://logintest20180704120701.azurewebsites.net/signout-oidc
   https://localhost:44319/signin-oidc
   https://logintest20180704120701.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc
```

The local host sign-in works fine. The app is simply the code created by Visual Studio by default with no modifications yet.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The reply URL should just be `<the URL of your app>/signin-oidc`, like `https://logintest20180704120701.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc`, if you published it. Please delete the `https://logintest20180704120701.azurewebsites.net/signout-oidc` This should be logout url.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the /signout-oidc from 'reply URLs'. The login problem is still there unfortunately.

Comment: Hi @Allen, Can you try to set `oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching` to be `true` in the AAD App manifest ?

Comment: Hi Wayne, Thanks for the suggestion. I did set this but still getting the error.

Comment: Ok, this isn't really an answer to the question I was asking but I think it's good information to share. I've came across a post that said authentication would only work in .NET Framework [(the post)](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/168976/authentication-with-azure-active-directory-missing.html), so that's what I tried. That worked for both projects where authentication was added at project creation time and when authentication was added via Connected Services. The only difference is the former adds code for signin/signout on the landing page and the latter doesn't.

Comment: The project that I'm trying to get authentication to work in is an ASP.NET Core (v2.1.300) project. I created both MVC and Web application projects to test. In both cases, 'change authentication' to 'work or school' cloud authentication is selected, but same error. I've tried making the return URL both https://<website>/signin-oidc and https://<website>/.auth/login/aad/callback, but same result. I'm assuming the intention is to support AAD authentication for ASP.NET Core applications since the option is available at project creation time, but I'm still missing something to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the Reply URL as the main url of your app and it needs to match the settings in the appsettings.json (and web.config if you have one). You do not appear to have a Reply URL set in your JSON so you need to add that there and in your solution. If you publish the solution you need to ensure that you change the Reply URL that you have set in your code to the published URL. This also needs to be set in your App Registration.

Please refer to [my blog post](https://medium.com/@marilee.turscak/reply-urls-vs-postlogoutredirecturis-in-azure-active-directory-aad-20f57a03267b) and accompanying [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9U1VGyztEM).

See also this [sample repository](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect) and documentation that should help you achieve what you are aiming for.